# Как задать структуру выбора?

Tags: delphi

Я делаю тестирование. Написал вопрос, а внизу 4 ответа (выбор осуществляется с помощью Radiobutton). Подсчет осуществляется с помощью gauge. Как задать правильно структуру if,
чтобы при при выборе правильного варианта ответа и нажатии соответсвующей кнопки, в gauge засчитывалось +5 процентов. Объясните, пожалуйста.

Comment: По нажатию на кнопку проверяйте, что выбрано в radio-группе. Если ответ правильный - увеличивайте gauge.

Answer (score 3):

Используйте вместо четырех `TRadioButton` один компонент - `TRadioGroup`. Он как раз предназначен для таких вещей. И пользоваться данным компонентом куда легче. Компонент имеет специальное свойство - **`ItemIndex`**, которое как раз возвращает номер выбранного радиобаттна (отсчет с нуля).

[Справка по TRadioGroup](http://www.beluch.ru/progr/100comp/5_4.htm).